# Generalize the sentence in $R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\phi(t)=m \left ((-\infty, t) \cap E\right )$, then $\phi$ is Lipschitz.

How could we generalize this sentence in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\phi(t)=m \left (\dots \cap E\right )$, then $\phi$ is Lipschitz.

What should be instead of $(-\infty, t)$ ?

Maybe a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Try with
$$
\phi(t) =  m\left(E\bigcap\prod_{i=1}^d (-\infty, t_i)\right).
$$

Comment: Aha... Ok! So, to show that $\phi$ is Lipschitz, we do the following:

$$|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|=|m \left (E\bigcap\prod_{i=1}^d (-\infty, x_i)\right)-m \left (E\bigcap\prod_{i=1}^d (-\infty, y_i)\right)|=\left |m \left [\left (E\bigcap\prod_{i=1}^d (-\infty, x_i)\right )\setminus \left (E\bigcap\prod_{i=1}^d (-\infty, y_i)\right )\right ]\right |$$

How could we continue??

Comment: can't you use the result for $d=1$ and induction?

Comment: So,we show that it stands for $d=1$. We suppose that it stands for each $i$ : $1\leq i\leq d-1$. Does this mean that $\forall 1\leq i\leq d-1$ we have that $$|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|\leq \Pi_{i=1}^{d-1}|x_i-y_i|$$?? Or isn`t that induction hypothesis??

Comment: Is the induction hypothesis correct??

Comment: I would try with the sum instead of the product.

Comment: What do you mean?? How can I use the sum??